# AWS CloudWatch Monitoring NetworkIn - no data points

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to see if an EC2 instance on AWS is receiving traffic from a streaming service (if no traffic is received i plan to close the instance).

To do this i measure the NetworkIn with a CloudWatchClient (with phpSDK). The problem is that when i put the 'Period' to 60 sec i receive no data points. The same code works fine if i put the period to 300(and adjust start and end time to a 300 sec interval) Any idea ?

```
 $time_const     =   60;// in sec
 $end_time       =   time();
 $start_time     =   $end_time-$time_const;


 $result = $cloudwatch_client->getMetricStatistics([
    'Dimensions' => [
        [
            'Name' => 'InstanceId', // REQUIRED
            'Value' => $InstanceId, // REQUIRED
        ],
    ],
    'EndTime'       => $end_time, // REQUIRED
    'StartTime'     => $start_time, // REQUIRED       
    'MetricName'    => 'NetworkIn', // REQUIRED
    'Namespace'     => 'AWS/EC2', // REQUIRED
    'Period'        => $time_const, // REQUIRED 
    'Unit'          => 'Bytes',
    'Statistics'    => array('Sum'),
    ]);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, EC2 CloudWatch metrics are only available on 5-minute (300 second) intervals. To monitor this at 60 second intervals, you need to [enable EC2 detailed monitoring](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-cloudwatch-new.html) for the given instance.  From the documentation:

> Data is available in 1-minute periods for an additional cost. To get this level of data, you must specifically enable it for the instance. For the instances where you've enabled detailed monitoring, you can also get aggregated data across groups of similar instances.

You can enable this from this AWS console, or via the CLI/SDK.  CLI example, from the linked documetation above:

```
aws ec2 monitor-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Do you know if there is a better way to measure traffic on a instance (other than Cloudwatch).?

Comment: Depends on what specifically you need to measure, but there are third-party tools available for just about anything you'd want to track.